# gradle sonar-scanner and sonar-scanner results are not same

Tags: sonarqube, build.gradle, sonar-runner

I want to analyze a multi language project with a sonarqube

Sonarqube version 6.7
Sonar-scanner version 2.6.1

but When running as **build.gradle**, java is only checked. When running with sonar-scanner, the all language(java,js,php etc.) is checked but coverage does not appear on the result screen.

this is my build.gradle

```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           maven {
             url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
                 }
               }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
              }
           }

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube{
        properties {
           property "sonar.projectKey", "projectkey"
           property "sonar.projectBaseDir", "/data1/repositories/project"
           property "sonar.sources", "./src/**"
        }
}

subprojects {
            apply plugin: 'jacoco'
            }
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
            }
    }

    test {
    ignoreFailures = true
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
           }
    }
```

The following command checks only java. "gradle sonarqube"

and

I trying next command

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=projectkey -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=$buildDir/jacoco/jacoco.exec
```

The follwing command check all language, but Not display coverage(Coverage result 0)

I wonder why the above two are different, and ultimately I want to check all languages and coverage with "gradle sonarqube".

Comment: Are you sure this `$buildDir` variable is correct in your context in this path: `-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths`. Try to hardcode it and run scanner to see if you can access coverage.

Comment: I tried the -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths property. 
As a result, the coverage of Sonar-Scanner was successful.
However, there was a problem of specifying each module in our project.
I confirmed that the attribute was not entered as a pattern.